# Thread safety in EE webservice

Tags: java, multithreading, web-services

Reading: https://abhirockzz.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/do-you-really-understand-webservice/comment-page-1/#comment-5862

"A POJO annotated with @WebService deployed in a WAR .. is not thread safe"
indeed "EJBs (annotated as @webservice) are thread safe by default"

I have a doubt, my company uses pojo annotated @Webservice (packed in war) that uses @EJB components (packed in JAR) all wrapped in a EE application ".ear".

All the logic is inside the ejb component, but a class variable stored inside the EJB is thread safe?

I have to realize a proxy webservice that calls in parallel other webservices and collect all responses, sort them and returns to the caller.

How should I realize it? I'm going to use in the proxy server a thread safe hashmap to collect temporary responses calling the other webservices in a async way (eg. using jax-ws callback mechanism).

Is this a right way?

[image: Schema]

EDIT:

@WebService(serviceName = "ProxyWS")
public class ProxyWS {

```
@EJB
private ProxyBeanLocal proxyBean;

@WebMethod(operationName = "hello")
public String hello(@WebParam(name = "name") String txt) {
    return proxyBean.businessMethod();
}
```

}

```
@Stateless
public class ProxyBean implements ProxyBeanLocal {

private final String ADAPTER_1_URL = "";
private final String ADAPTER_2_URL = "";
ConcurrentMap<String, String> m;

@Override
public String businessMethod() {

    try {
        m = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

        AdapterWS_Service serviceAdapter = new AdapterWS_Service(new URL(ADAPTER_1_URL));
        AdapterWS adapter = serviceAdapter.getAdapterWSPort();

        adapter.helloAsync("", this);//call async with callback on this

        serviceAdapter = new AdapterWS_Service(new URL(ADAPTER_2_URL));
        adapter = serviceAdapter.getAdapterWSPort();

        adapter.helloAsync("", this);


    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProxyBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return null; //return recordset once all responses arrived (using blocking queue?)

}

@Override
public void handleResponse(Response<HelloResponse> res) {
    try {
        m.put(res.get().getReturn(), res.get().getReturn());
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProxyBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProxyBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endpoint implementation annotated with `@WebService` may be invoked from the different threads. Here's the relevant part of the [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxws-2_3-mrel5-eval-spec/jaxws-2.3.pdf):

> An Endpoint will be typically invoked to serve concurrent requests, so
>   its implementor should be written so as to support multiple threads.
>   The synchronized keyword may be used as usual to control access to
>   critical sections of code

If you want to have a class variable of the type `ConcurrentMap` this may not work for you if it is expected that the map should contain results of processing on one specific call from client. The reason is that if two calls are processed concurrently then data from these two invocations will get into that map. Even that this will not break the structure of the map on the low level the returned data will most probably be inconsistent (like mix of the data from two requests).

You need to isolate the data from the other requests that are running. And class variable does not do that. Stack variable or thread local should do. There may also be a problem of how you fetch data from WebService1...WebServiceN. If this is done in some other threads then you need to synchronize access to that map of cause but that is not part of the issue with `@WebSerivce` concurrency.

Think what happen if two clients call `hello` endpoint and `businessMethod` concurrently. The responses from services will be put to the same `ConcurrentHashMap` in `handleResponse`.

One way to overcome this is to create `AsyncHandler` that will have a reference to the map created for handling of the specific request like this:

```
public static ResponsesCollector implements AsyncHandler<HelloResponse> {
   private Map<String, String> responses = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
   @Override
   public void handleResponse(Response<HelloResponse> res) {
      responses.put(res.get().getReturn(), res.get().getReturn());
   }
   public Map<String, String> getResponses() {
      return responses; 
   }
}


@Override
public String businessMethod() {

    try {
        ResponsesCollector responsesCollector = new ResponsesCollector()

        AdapterWS_Service serviceAdapter = new AdapterWS_Service(new URL(ADAPTER_1_URL));
        AdapterWS adapter = serviceAdapter.getAdapterWSPort();

        adapter.helloAsync("", responsesCollector);

        serviceAdapter = new AdapterWS_Service(new URL(ADAPTER_2_URL));
        adapter = serviceAdapter.getAdapterWSPort();

        adapter.helloAsync("", responsesCollector);

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ProxyBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    // ideally here you need return control to container
    // and resume processing inside responseCollector
    // when the last response is gotten. The problem is that JAX-WS does not
    // specify how to do async processing on server side (similar to Async Servlets in Servlets specification 3.x).
    // I know only one implementation that has an extension for async WebMethod -
    // JEUS, see https://technet.tmaxsoft.com/upload/download/online/jeus/pver-20160610-000001/web-service/chapter_jaxws_async_operation.html
    // So the only portable option here is to wait (using container thread).

    // 

    return null; //return recordset once all responses arrived (using blocking queue?)

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added an example to better undertstand what I'm going to do. Do you think that should cause inconsistency?

Comment: Yes, this implementation has the problem that I described in the answer.

Comment: I've added a sketch of the idea how to fix this issue @FrancescoUmani